# Is there a way to escape SpEL characters "#{" in a Spring property value

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring boot, and have the following config in my application.yml

`apiKey: ${API_KEY}`

API_KEY is randomly generated and contains "#{" (like "sksjd#{lsd8") which denotes the beginning of a SpEL expression
(https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef). This causes spring to try to interpret the expression and then fail since there's no closing brace.

I want the string to just be interpreted literally, and I'd like to not have to regenerate this key, and have tried:

`apiKey: "${API_KEY}"`

`apiKey: '${API_KEY}'`

`apiKey: "#{'${API_KEY}'}"`

`apiKey: '#{"${API_KEY}"}'`

Update:
I was testing these changes in a dependent library, and it turns out that I was still pulling in the master version of the library instead of the local version with changes.

`apiKey: "#{'${API_KEY}'}"` does work

Comment: Are you sure this is not working when you use this `@Value("#{'${API_KEY}'}")` in your java code? I just tried and I see the value printing _sksjd#{lsd8_

Comment: I just tried this in java code, an it doesn't work for me, I still get `No ending suffix '}' for expression`

Comment: Can you add the full code? I understand you'll get this error `No ending suffix '}' for expression starting` when you're using `"${API_KEY}"` as you're referring the property directly without using SpEL but you shouldn't get error `@Value("#{'${API_KEY}'}")`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apiKey: "#{'${API_KEY}'}"` does work after all, as does Prakash's answer which helped me realize why it looked like nothing I was trying worked.

Answer (score 0):

In case, someone else looking for a fix. What worked for me is, SpEL and other special characters can be escaped as follows:

```
apiKeyPattern : '[${API_KEY}]'
```

This will result in literal ${API_KEY}